# Doctrine SELECT d.user AS user not allowed?

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I try to do a `SELECT d.user AS user` type of query. But this part is not allowed in Doctrine it seems.

I try to get a nice array as follows:

```
array(
   'week' => 39
   'year' => 2016
   'user' => UserObject{}
```

I have the following DQL:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select("d.user AS user, WEEK(d.date, 3) AS week, DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%x') AS year")
        ->join('d.user', 'u')
        ->orderBy('d.date', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();
```

Of course, I can do a `select("d, etc` however I want to directly have the user as a key in the returning array.

The error I get with the above code is:
`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'user AS user,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

I have already added the join, but that seems not to help.

Comment: I think you're taking the problem on the wrong side. If you want to retrieve an user, shouldn't your query be on the user entity and the join for your conditions on the other entity? Another lead is that `user` is a reserved keyword in many SGBD (don't know which one you're using), you may need to change the alias or putting it between ` quotes.

Comment: @Boulzy, thanks for your reply! I already changed the allias, but that didn't help. The reason I come with this question is that I *can* do a `->select('d, ...)` That way I have the user also. I only want to directly select the user, so that the data array is just as I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will give you exactly the result you want (maybe you will have to try the `Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` hydrator), but can something like that do the trick?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->select("user, WEEK(d.date, 3) AS week, DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%x') AS year")
            ->leftJoin('d.user', 'user')
            ->orderBy('d.date', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();

return $qb->getResult();
```